# Reactjs Route Doesn't Return Correct Result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 3 apps with this structure:

```
import React from 'react'
export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>Hey App1!</div>
    }
})

import React from 'react'
export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>Hey App2!</div>
    }
})

import React from 'react'
export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>Hey App3!</div>
    }
})
```

And in my `main.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App1 from './modules/App1.js'
import App2 from './modules/App2.js'
import App3 from './modules/App3.js'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App1}>
      <IndexRoute component={App1} />
      <Route path="app1" component={App2} />
      <Route path="app2" component={App3} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

But when I try `/#/app1` or `/#/app2` addresses in my browser it shows the `/` result (it means 'Hey App1").

My Reactjs version is: `15.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your preferred history is `browserHistory`. Then the URLs should look like `example.com/some/path`.

So try `/app1` or `/app2`  without hash in the url.

Hash history uses the hash (#) portion of the URL, creating routes that look like example.com/#/some/path.

If you want to use hash in the url pass `hashHistory` as props instead of `browserHistory`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine when I add all Routes in the same level. How to fix it when I use `/` as a parent Route? (as I did it in my example `IndexRoute`)

Comment: what is the problem when  / is added as parent route

Comment: Actually this code works: `<Route path="/" component={App1}></Route><Route path="/app1" component={App1}></Route><Route path="/app2" component={App2}></Route>` but this code doesn't: `<Route path="/" component={App1}><Route path="app1" component={App1}></Route> <Route path="app2" component={App2}></Route></Route>`